# Attribute in C# for @BeforeSuite annotation in java testNG

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit

Do we have any attribute in C# (NUnit) similar to @BeforeSuite annotation in Java (Selenium TestNG)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See: https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Attributes

I think you are looking for OneTimeSetup.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [docs](https://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=setup&r=2.2.10) you can use `SetUpAttribute` :

```
[SetUp] 
public void Init()
{

}
```

Comment: I wanted few settings to run only once while executing my test suite and SetUp will run before every test.right?